# Как в php переформировать массив?

Tags: php

Имеется массив вида:

```
$array = [['a' => 1], ['b' => 2]];
```

Данный массив из такого вида должен превратиться вот в такой:

```
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];
```

Как средствами PHP это можно сделать? Желательно без foreach если это возможно.

Comment: т.е. из списка словарей вы хотите сделать словарь

Comment: `$result = array_merge(...$arr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант через [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php):

```
$array = [['a' => 1], ['b' => 2]];
$new_array = array_merge(...$array);

var_dump($new_array);
```

---

Вариант через циклы:

```
$array = [['a' => 1], ['b' => 2]];

$new_array = [];
foreach ($array as $x) {
    foreach ($x as $k => $v) {
        $new_array[$k] = $v;
    }
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

---

Если уверены, что внутри всегда будет словари с одним ключом, тогда одним циклом:

```
$array = [['a' => 1], ['b' => 2]];

$new_array = [];
foreach ($array as $x) {
    $new_array[key($x)] = current($x);
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

---

Результат:

```
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(1)
  ["b"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Comment: судя по постановке задачи, во вложенном массиве только одна пара ключ-значение, так что смысла во вложенном цикле нет.

Comment: @teran, что-то вроде: `$k = array_key_first($x);` `$new_array[$k] = $x[$k];`?

Comment: попроще - `$new_array[key($x)] = current($x)`

Comment: @teran, круто, спасибо!

Comment: Вариант с array_merge отличный. Спасибо!